# Looping through HTML elements to get specific innerTexts on click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add javascript to a shopping cart template I got from the internet. My goal is to be able to access each elements name, price and image src stored in their independent variable and so that if I press the "Add to cart" button, I can be able to console.log() either the name, price or image src of the specific item I want to add to cart. Please note that *I am fairly new to Javascript*. Any help would be appreciated

```
<section class="py-5">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
        <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
        {% for item in items %}
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pocket-lint.com/r/s/x1920/assets/images/161396-laptops-review-hands-on-macbook-air-review-image1-v2jzcb3rqd.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center text-dark">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder ">{{ item.name }}</h5>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            ${{item.price}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Sale badge-->
                    <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">AirPods Pro</h5>
                            <!-- Product reviews-->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$20.00</span>
                            <span class="price">$18.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Sale badge-->
                    <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Ps5</h5>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$50.00</span>
                            <span class="price">$25.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Popular Item</h5>
                            <!-- Product reviews-->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="price">$40.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Sale badge-->
                    <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Sale Item</h5>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$50.00</span>
                            <span class="price">$25.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Fancy Product</h5>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="price">$120.00 - $280.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Sale badge-->
                    <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Special Item</h5>
                            <!-- Product reviews-->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$20.00</span>
                            <span class="price">$18.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-5">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <!-- Product image-->
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <!-- Product details-->
                    <div class="card-body p-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Product name-->
                            <h5 class="fw-bolder">Popular Item</h5>
                            <!-- Product reviews-->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product price-->
                            <span class="price">$40.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Product actions-->
                    <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                        <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
```

I am using jina templating and flask for this project.

**I have tried**

```
let add_to_cart_btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-success')

    for(let i=0; i<add_to_cart_btns.length; i++){
        add_to_cart_btns[i].addEventListener('click', addToCart)
    }
    
    function addToCart(event){
        let btn = event.target

        let item_name= document.getElementsByClassName('fw-bolder')
        let item_price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')
        let item_image = document.getElementsByClassName('card-img-top')

        Array.from(item_name).forEach(function(element) {
            let item_name = element.innerHTML
        });
        
        Array.from(item_price).forEach(function(element) {
            let item_price = element.innerHTML
        });
    }
```

but I notice each time I click "add to cart" it stores all the item names under "item_name" instead of just the specific item's button I clicked

Comment: It turns out that I needed to pass the item names through Jinja templating to "let item_name =" I should have looped through my items, '{%for item in items%}' let item = '{{item.name}}' {% endear %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select product details based on its relevant button. This would probably involve going up from the button to a common parent then target the proper information. We shall use javascript and css selectors.

```js
let add_to_cart_btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success')

for (let i = 0; i < add_to_cart_btns.length; i++) {
  add_to_cart_btns[i].addEventListener('click', addToCart)
}

function addToCart(event) {
  let btn = event.target

  var card = btn.closest(".card");
  let item_name = card.querySelector('.fw-bolder').innerText
  let item_image = card.querySelector('.card-img-top').getAttribute("src");

  var copy = card.querySelector('.card-body>.text-center').cloneNode(true);
  copy.querySelector(".fw-bolder").remove();
  let item_price = copy.innerText.trim();

  console.log(item_name, item_image, item_price)

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.card-img-top {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="py-5">
  <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
      {% for item in items %}
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pocket-lint.com/r/s/x1920/assets/images/161396-laptops-review-hands-on-macbook-air-review-image1-v2jzcb3rqd.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center text-dark">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder ">{{ item.name }}</h5>
              <!-- Product price-->
              ${{item.price}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Sale badge-->
          <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">AirPods Pro</h5>
              <!-- Product reviews-->
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$20.00</span>
              <span class="price">$18.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Sale badge-->
          <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Ps5</h5>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$50.00</span>
              <span class="price">$25.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Popular Item</h5>
              <!-- Product reviews-->
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="price">$40.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Sale badge-->
          <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Sale Item</h5>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$50.00</span>
              <span class="price">$25.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Fancy Product</h5>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="price">$120.00 - $280.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Sale badge-->
          <div class="badge bg-dark text-white position-absolute" style="top: 0.5rem; right: 0.5rem">Sale</div>
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Special Item</h5>
              <!-- Product reviews-->
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">$20.00</span>
              <span class="price">$18.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <!-- Product image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." />
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
              <!-- Product name-->
              <h5 class="fw-bolder">Popular Item</h5>
              <!-- Product reviews-->
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Product price-->
              <span class="price">$40.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product actions-->
          <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline btn-success" href="#">Add to cart</a>
              <a href="{{url_for('more_info')}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">More Info</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, This worked, though I found a solution that is shorter